# Shell Script IP Neighbor Refresh

Tags: shell, ip, refresh, arp, neighbours

I am working on an application of multiple devices in the same network. One of them takes the lead and performs some functions. I arbitrate the "lead" by the highest IP I find.

My application is intended to be fault-tolerant and if I loose the controller, next in the line should take over.
I am running the script below.

```
#define SHELLSCRIPT "\
    #/bin/bash \n\
    echo $(ifconfig | grep -A 1 'eth0' | tail -1 | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1) > IP.txt\n\
    while read LINE; do echo $LINE | grep -i -E 192.168 | grep -v .254 | cut -c1-13; done < /proc/net/arp >> IP.txt\n\
    "
```

The problem I have found is that the ARP cache does not refresh automatically. Does anyone has any idea how to "refresh" the ARP table (without using arp commands).
I have already tried "ip -s neigh flush all", but it seems to have a delay to refresh the ARP table.

Anyway, I would appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable and enable the use of the ARP protocol on interface at the same time.
ARP cache will be cleared quitly fast.

```
ip link set arp off dev eth0 ; ip link set arp on dev eth0
```

Please, at first run this on test environment for checking and be sure there no connection interruption.

Comment: Hi Alexey, thank you for the suggestion. I have tried it but it works randomly. Some times it updates immediately, some others it takes from 10 to 20 seconds and occasionally it never refresh. Best regards.

Comment: @julianop99 Did you check ARP table with command `ip neigh show` for comparison?

Comment: @julianop99 Did you find solution of issue?